# B=A if B is a definable subset of A and B contains all $\mathfrak{A}$-standard elements of A.

Tags: solution-verification, model-theory

I have been assigned a homework question and I believe I am missing some steps I need to take to proceed. First some context:

> Let $\mathfrak{A} = (A,<_0)$ be a structure such that $(A,<_0)\equiv(\mathbb{N},<)$. An element $a\in A$ is called $\mathfrak{A}$-standard if and only if $\{b\in A\mid b<_0 a\}$ is a finite set.

Now suppose $B\subseteq A$ is a definable subset, that is there exists a formula $\varphi = \varphi(x,x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n-1})$ and a sequence $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}$ in $A$ such that for every $a\in A$ we have $a\in B$ iff $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi[a,b_0,b_1,\dots, b_{n-1}]$.

Furthermore, $B$ contains every $\mathfrak{A}$-standard elements from $A$. The question is to prove that $B=A$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $a\in A$. We can assume that $a$ is a non $\mathfrak{A}$-standard element. This means that the set $\{b\in A\mid b<_0 a\}$ is infinite. The goal is to show that with this information, we can determine a sequence $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_{n-1}$ in $A$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi[a,b_0,b_1,\dots, b_{n-1}]$. I assumed that every definable subset of $A$ is either finite or co-finite (I did this because I remember this was the case for any naked structure and I hoped (for now) that this would be the case).

Then I convinced myself that there are infinite $\mathfrak{A}$-standard elements. This assumption is more justified because $\mathfrak{A}\equiv(\mathbb{N},<)$ and I figured in quick thinking that some formula will not be true in $\mathfrak{A}$ while being true in $(\mathbb{N}, <)$.

The wishful thinking amounts to the observation that $A\setminus B$ must be finite.
Now I just hope that we can conclude that $A\setminus B$ is the empty set.

So is this the way to go and if so, how do I show my assumptions are true? Is this completely wrong and if so, how do I approach this problem differently? I thank you in advance.

Comment: Your assumption that any definable set of $A$ is either finite or co-finite is not reasonable at all since the theory of $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ is definitely not strongly minimal (it is not even stable since we have an infinite linear order).

Comment: Isn't this obviously false? Let $b$ be an element which is greater than every standard element. Then the set defined by $x<b$ contains all the standard elements but does not contain $b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman wait why should there exist such a $b$? As far as I can see the set of standards elements of $A$ can be as big as $A$, which causes saturation issues.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I don't know what you mean by "saturation issues". If $A$ has only standard elements, the statement is vacuously true (and $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$). If $A$ has any non-standard element $b$, it must be greater than all standard elements. For an easier version of my counterexample, let $b$ be any non-standard element and consider the formula $x\neq b$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman indeed, I suppose that there is an assumption missing in OP. What if $B$ is required to be definable over the standard elements?

Comment: The exact wording of the question is: "Prove: If $B\subseteq A$ is an $\mathfrak{A}$-definable subset of $A$ that contains all $\mathfrak{A}$-standard elements of A, then $B=A.$ I can understand the counterexample given so I will ask my professor about this situation ASAP